# Sprockets directives and slim templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, sprockets, slim-lang

I'm trying get work Sprockets directives in Slim templates inside rails assets pipeline.

This is how I embed slim into pipeline:

```
config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.register_mime_type 'text/slim', extensions: ['.slim']
  env.register_engine '.slim', Slim::Template, mime_type: 'text/slim'
  env.register_preprocessor 'text/html', Sprockets::DirectiveProcessor.new(comments: ["//"])
  env.register_preprocessor 'text/slim', Sprockets::DirectiveProcessor.new(comments: ["//"])
end
```

But directives like depend_on or require don't recognized by pipeline inside slim templates in development environment.

I have Rails 4.2.4. and Sprockets 3.4.0

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: I think this won't work for sprockets 3+.

Comment: Why? In Sprockets sources all preprocessors registered this way https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/3.x/lib/sprockets.rb#L96

Comment: Ah, you're probably right. I'm having issues with sprockets as well. Not the same issue as yours though.